# Python pass a class reference to another class during construction

Tags: python

I'm intending to create a data distributor class as a mutable class:

```
class DataDistributor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.target_trackid = -1

    def next_sen(self):
        self.target_trackid += 1
        return self.target_trackid
```

So that I can globally keep a pointer on my data.

I have another class:

```
class Env(object):
      def __init__(self, distributor):
           self.distributor = distributor
           self.target_trackid = 0  # init
      def reset(self):
           self.target_trackid = self.distributor.next_sen()
```

So that when I create many `Env` instances, each `Env` instance will get a different data point.

So I use this to create my instances:

```
ddist = DataDistributor()
env = Env(ddist)
envs = [pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(env)) for _ in range(12)]

envs[0].reset()
envs[1].reset()
envs[2].reset()

print envs[0].target_trackid
print envs[1].target_trackid
print envs[2].target_trackid
```

And the results are all the same: a bunch of 0s.

I'm not exactly sure how Python is handling this :( and if there is a viable solution to achieve what I want to achieve!

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. What is the point of dumping and immediately loading the pickle? And what output are you expecting?

Comment: You want to have _one_ instance of `Env`. Right now unpickling creates new instances based on pickled state.

Comment: Ahhhh!!!! Yes. I did not notice that `pickle` is the problem. I didn't write the `pickle` part of code, that's inside the library I'm trying to use. I changed that part and now it works! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a *class variable* for keeping track of the objects created? Your simple class structure will be like:

```
class Env(object):
    my_counter = 0    # Your class variable

    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        # some initialization
        Env.my_counter += 1   # increament everytime object is created
        # some logic
```

Sample run:

```
>>> e1 = Env('p11', 'p12')  # creation of first object
>>> Env.my_counter
1     # value of counter set as 1

>>> e1 = Env('p21', '22')   # creation of second object
>>> Env.my_counter
2     # value of counter set as 2
```

Passing object of different class just for tracking the created object of some other class, it is definitely not the right approach.

Comment: I didn't know class variable's existence. This is a much better answer! Thanks!

Comment: Ahh..I don't think this solves the concrete problem though...`envs = [pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(env)) for _ in range(12)]` is in someone else's library that I can't control. It seems like when doing this, the method (+1 to my_counter) is called 12 times before I call reset(). And they still end up being the same number...

Comment: Do you know when you do `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(env))`, you are not actually creating a new object? `env` is all the time referencing to the same object

Comment: I really don't know...that line is not my code, but someone else's library's code.

Comment: But I managed to override it...and now everything works. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score -2):

`pickle.load` will create different objects which means the `datadistributor` variable in each `env` object will refere

Comment: It seems your answer is incomplete, please edit it to add any missing information.